# How to refresh treeview when ItemsSource changes?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, refresh

My TreeView is bound to an ObservableCollection and uses HierarchicalDataTemplates.

I get the models from a web service.

Only when users click a node in tree, a web service call will be sent to get its child items.

My App has a TabControl, TreeView is on one tabpage, the other tabpage has a datagrid - it has some data selected from treeview. When an item in datagrid is right clicked, I want to locate the item on treeview.  But now the issue is when I iterate the treeview, 
say, I have an item called

> A.A1.A11

and my TreeView has 3 items in the first level:

A
B
C

when I locate **A.A1.A11**, I want to *expand* A, A1, and *highlight* A11.

When I iterate the treeview, first I find A, it matches first path of A.A1.A11, 
so I send a web service request to get A's children.

Once I get that, DataContext of the TreeViewItem of A is updated, but the TreeViewItem itself is not.

So when I check A.Items, it is empty and iteratation is unable to continue.

**How can I refresh the TreeView & TreeViewItem when its ItemsSource changes?**

Here is the xaml for treeview definition

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeRoot" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding RootItems}" 
          TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewExpanded"
          TreeView.SelectedItemChanged="TreeRootSelectedItemChanged"
          ContextMenu="{StaticResource DataGridContextMenu}"
          PreviewKeyDown="TreeViewKeyDown"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TreeViewPreviewLeftMouseButtonDown"
          PreviewMouseMove="TreeViewPreviewMouseMove" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            DataType="{x:Type m:TreeModelBase}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">    
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageFilePath}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <!-- other items removed for brevity -->
                <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                     Value="True">  
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" 
                                Value="White"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                     Value="False">  
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" 
                                Value="Black"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are updating the items in the bound collection(s)?

Comment: @EtherGragon, update in expand        public void TreeViewExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
            if (item == null) return;
            var treeModel = item.DataContext as TreeModelBase;

            ExpandSelected(treeModel);
        }

        private void ExpandSelected(TreeModelBase treeModel)
        {
            if (treeModel == null) return;
            if (ViewModel == null) return;
            ViewModel.CloseNotificationBar();
            ViewModel.RetrieveChildRels(treeModel);           
        }

Comment: @toosensitive: [edit] works, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found & managed to get it work. but it is really not optimal at all.  What I did,  iterate viewModel first,  send web service request to get A's children, then send another request to get A1's children.  This is the first pass. Second, search treeview from root and generate ItemContainers while iteration. First, search root of tree, get node A (treeviewItem), then apply  template,  get container from ItemContainerGenerator (see detail @ [How to refresh treeview when ItemsSource changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086548/how-to-refresh-treeview-when-itemssource-change)), then I am able to find the item on treeview and expand its path.  Anyone knows a better way, let me know. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does RootItems implement INotifyProperty changed and are you calling NotifyPropertyChanged?   Collections need to be an ObservableCollection (not a List) for the UI to know about updates.

Comment: Yes, RootItems implement INotifyProperty, when I get result from web service, I call OnPropertyChanged("Children"),   both RootItems, and Children are ObservableCollection<T> where T implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I know this basic just covering the basics.  RootItems is a public property?   Put a trace on the get and see if it gets called when you expect it to.   Are you updating the public (set) property (not the private member behind it)?    You can put a higher level trace on the binding that start with PresentationTra...  but I don't think that is your problem if it binds the first time.  I am with Jacob on ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0):

When populating TreeViewItem's children, you don't update DataContext, you update ItemsSource. So after the service gets the children for A, you need to assign the resulting List (or ObservableCollection) to A.ItemsSource.

Comment: thanks. You mean A.ItemSource = collection? I thougth they are bound and no need to explicitly do this. also In ViewModel, it has no reference to view (A). How can do this assignment?

Comment: A lot depends on how and where you are adding items from the service call. For example, what type, exactly, is RootItems in your example? Is that a CollectionViewSource? Or a List? Or something else? WPF data binding is extremely flexible, but you pay for that in complexity.

Comment: thanks. RootItems is ObservableCollection<TreeModelBase>, Children is the same type. When ViewModel is contructed, I will populate RootItems. After that, when users click to expand a node on tree, I will expand the node by one level.

Comment: Makes sense. An observable collection *should* update automatically when items are added to the collection. Here's a question: when the web service returns is it replacing the collection? It shouldn't. When the treeview initially binds, it's binding to a specific object instance so the web service should be adding items to the existing observable collection rather than replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using DataContext and proper data binding technique, **update** of the TreeViewItem can be achieved by connecting PropertyChanged to each item and deriving TreeViewItem like mentioned below (resetting DataContext and template of the tree item).
This example refreshes only 2nd level items (second condition), might be easily extended of course.

In my case ElementItem is the base class for every item in ObservableList and implements INotifyProperty.

```
    ...

    itemInObservableList.PropertyChanged += Ep_PropertyChanged;

    ...

    private void Ep_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            var twi = this.pageList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(
                (sender as ElementItem).Parent ) as TreeViewItem;
            if (twi != null)
            {
                var twii = twi.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(sender) as TreeViewItem;
                if (twii != null)
                {
                 //second level items refresh   
                    var dc = twii.DataContext;
                    var tpl = twii.Template;
                    twii.DataContext = null;
                    twii.Template = null;
                    twii.DataContext = sender ;
                    twii.Template = tpl;
                    twii.UpdateLayout();
                }  
            }
    }
```